# MILP constraint for connected node selection

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming, constraints, mixed-integer-programming

I am formulating constraints for a network as shown in Figure [image: Network].

Blue circles represent a set of nodes, $N = \{1, 2, \ldots, 5\}$. Three different types of devices are connected to different nodes in the network. Some of the devices are shared among multiple nodes, e.g., device 2 (in sun shape) is connected with nodes 1, 2, and 4. I want to select the minimum number of nodes where the following constraint should meet.

1. A node $T$ must be selected. This $T$ can be any node from blue circles in the network.
2. At least $k$ nodes from blue circles should be selected that are connected to rectangle-shaped $G$ device. In the above figure, $k$ can be node 2 or node 4 or both if $k$ is 2.
3. There should be a path between any two pairs of selected nodes. It means that the selected graph should not be disconnected.

I have written the following MILP formulation.

$$\min \sum_{i\in N} x_{i}$$

The constraints are as follows:

$$x_{T} = 1$$
$$\sum_{i\in N} G_{i} \cdot x_{i} \ge k$$
$$\sum_{i\in N, i \ne j} \text{ConnectedNodes}_{i, j} \cdot x_{i} \ge x_{j} \quad \forall j \in N$$

The connectivity constraint is not working correctly and I am not sure how can I enforce constraint 3. I have seen some examples of subgraph generation to ensure connectivity. However, in my case, the selected number of nodes is dynamic. For example, if we fix the value of $k$ to 1, then only node 2 will be selected if node $T$ is node 2. Only nodes 1 and 2 will be selected if node $T$ is node 1. Similarly, nodes 2, 3, and 5 will be selected if node $T$ is node 5. Any help or suggestion in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/159983/755

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for sharing the link. I think the problem in my case is different because if I consider node T as a source node, then it will check the vertices only on one side. In my case, the vertices can be explored on both sides of node T to meet the constraints. Furthermore, the question at the above link does not address the selection of the nearest node(s) and device(s) first.

Comment: OK!  I just thought it might be helpful to see the technique.  Regarding your question, I think it's too much for this website.  We're looking to build a library/archive of questions that will be useful to others.  There are so many details in your question (suns, triangles, rectangles, 7 rules, oh my), which makes it unlikely this will be relevant to others, and make it quite time-consuming to understand the question.

Comment: I suggest you try to boil down what is the key aspect that you are having difficulty with (is it expressing connectivity constraints? something else?) and formulate the simplest possible problem that contains that element and that you can't solve.

Comment: Regarding your constraints, I doubt that debugging what's wrong with a MILP formulation is on-topic on this site.

Comment: The elements are interrelated to the whole problem that's why I designed a figure to make it easier to understand. I am facing difficulty with only two constraints: (1) connectivity constraint and (2) selection constraint for selecting the devices first which are directly connected to node T and then selecting devices in the nearest first nodes until the required number of devices are selected.

Comment: You've just repeated what you already said in the question you are having difficulty with, and I already saw that.  I suggest you try to generate a minimal problem that relates to connectivity -- an artificial toy problem that is the simplest you can think of that you don't know how to solve -- and then ask about that.  This problem statement is so complex that I don't think your odds of getting an answer are good, and the odds it is useful to anyone in the future don't seem good either.